# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'result_l' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I was trying to solve [leetcode 965](https://leetcode.com/problems/univalued-binary-tree/) of checking whether a binary tree is univalued. While I experienced the error of UnboundLocalError. How should I solve this problem?

```
class Solution:

    def isUnivalTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        if not root:
            return True
        if not root.left:
            result_l = (root.left.val == root.val) and self.isUnivalTree(root.left)
        if not root.right:
            result_r = (root.right.val == root.val) and self.isUnivalTree(root.right)

        return result_l and result_r
```

I understand there's any other way to do it which using conditional statements  in one line. I try to break a one line statement down in a clearer way like using if-else because I want to learn more about the data structure.

(code below can run successfully)

```
class Solution:

    def isUnivalTree(self, root: TreeNode) -> bool:
        if not root:
            return True

        result_l = (not root.left) or (root.left.val == root.val) and self.isUnivalTree(root.left)
        result_r = (not root.right) or (root.right.val == root.val) and self.isUnivalTree(root.right)

        return result_l and result_r
```

Comment: Preset the "result_..." variables with False.

Comment: Which example had the problem? I bet its #1.... suppose `root.left` has a value, then the `if` block doesn't run, `result_l` is not assigned and there you go.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelButscher and @tdelaney!